# DocuSign JWT request invalid_grant unsupported_grant_type

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I'm working on my first DocuSign web service consumer, in the development environment.  At this point, I'm just trying to duplicate the token request procedure on DocuSign's how-to page: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/
I'm sticking as closely as possible to the process shown in their YouTube video.  I have created an app with an integration key and an RSA key pair (generated by DocuSign).  I obtained application consent as per step 1 of the how-to.

As per step 2 of the how-to page, I entered the following request in jwt.io:

Header: {"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256"}

Payload: {"iss":"(integration key GUID)","sub":"(API username GUID)","iat":1619972504,"exp":1619975504,"aud":"account-d.docusign.com","scope":"signature"}

I pasted the public and private keys, including the starting and ending strings, into the appropriate fields, and jwt.io created and verified a signature.

As per step 3 and the YouTube video, in Postman, I created a POST request to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token with
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion=(encoded token copied from jwt.io)

No matter what I do, the web service always returns
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "unsupported_grant_type"
}

I've spent more time than I care to admit re-reading the how-to page, re-watching the YouTube video therein, and poring over my data for typos, etc.

Ideas, anyone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 you would also need the scope of "impersonation" for JWT.

Comment: The how-to page and the video explicitly show "signature" scope only.  I changed the scope to "signature impersonation", didn't do it.

Comment: To clarify, my application consent URL in step 1 did have scope "signature impersonation":
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=integration_key&redirect_uri=http://www.docusign.com

Comment: Send an email to go-live@docusign.com with your integration key and I will take a further look